# Repeated column in mapping for entity @OneToOne should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Hi I am trying below Entity classes for JPA Operations . I am getting an error Repeated column in mapping for entity @OneToOne should be mapped with insert="false" update="false" for column LOAN_ID . I tried some options and tried to follow some suggestions in other posts but nothing seems work , every try its giving some error . What is the mistake i am doing .

```
LOAN_UNDERWRITING - PK is LOAN_ID
LOAN_UNDERWRITING_STATUS - PK is LOAN_ID and UWS_ADD_DATE
Loans  - PK is LOAN_ID
```

Root Entity Class

```
public class Loans {
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "LOAN_ID")
private LoanUnderWriting loanUnderWriting;
}
```

LOAN_UNDERWRITING - Entity Class

```
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "LOAN_UNDERWRITING")
@Entity
public class LoanUnderWriting {

@Id
@Column(name = "LOAN_ID")
private Long loanId;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({ 
    @JoinColumn(name = "UW_ADD_DATE"), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOAN_ID") })
private LoanUnderWritingStatus loanUnderWritingStatus;
}
```

LOAN_UNDERWRITING_STATUS-Entity Class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "LOAN_UNDERWRITING_STATUS")
@Entity
public class LoanUnderWritingStatus {

@EmbeddedId
private LoanUnderWritingStatusId loanUnderWritingStatusId;
}
```

LoanUnderWritingStatusId Class

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Embeddable
public class LoanUnderWritingStatusId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "LOAN_ID")
private Long loanId;

@Column(name = "UWS_ADD_DATE")
private String uwsAddDate;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping should have `insertable = false, updatable = false` in `LoanUnderWriting` Entity for `LoanUnderWritingStatus` as showun below.

```
@DynamicUpdate
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "LOAN_UNDERWRITING")
@Entity
public class LoanUnderWriting {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "LOAN_ID")
  private Long loanId;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumns({ 
    @JoinColumn(name = "UW_ADD_DATE", referencedColumnName = "UW_ADD_DATE", insertable = false, updatable = false), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "LOAN_ID", referencedColumnName = "LOAN_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
  private LoanUnderWritingStatus loanUnderWritingStatus;
}
```

Comment: If i add this i am getting another error saying 
Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed

Comment: @Vinoy Could you try adding `, insertable = false, updatable = false` to as well UW_ADD_DATE, updated the answer

Comment: ya i tried that , Then i am getting error saying could not extract ResultSet

Comment: @Vinoy Then you have a new error now. Could you add your error?

Comment: yes Query Forming incorrectly . Looking into that . Will respond to your answer .

Comment: Now its forming like below

Comment: select * from 
LOAN_UNDERWRITING loanunderw0_ 
left outer join LOAN_UNDERWRITING_STATUS loanunderw1_ 
on loanunderw0_.UW_ADD_DATE=loanunderw1_.LOAN_ID 
and loanunderw0_.LOAN_ID=loanunderw1_.UWS_ADD_DATE

Comment: Its swapping the columns while joining

Comment: You can use `, referencedColumnName = "UW_ADD_DATE"` as updated in answer

Comment: ya tried that , Since UW_ADD_DATE is in LoanUnderWritingStatusId  , i tried like loanUnderWritingStatusId.uwsAddDate . But its not identifying 
Unable to find column with logical name

Comment: May be it has to be treated as another issue.